Verification of sheaf condition
Let $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$ be an etale space associated to  a given  sheaf $\mathcal {F}$ over a topolofical space X . Let
$\mathcal{C}^{0}(\mathcal{F} )(U)=\lbrace  s: U\rightarrow \tilde{\mathcal{F}} | \pi \circ s=id_{U }$ where $s$ need not be continuous $\rbrace $ where $\pi $ is a projection map that sends $\mathcal{F}_{x}$ to x.
My question is how this presheaf is actually a sheaf I dont see how it satisfies two sheaf axioms ?
I mean how can we glue up discontinuos section to obtain a global section how to verify that it forms  a sheaf . 
Or Is it trivially true that I am not being able to figure it out?   Your help is highly appreciated. Thank You

It is, actually, very straightforward. So we can't really help unless you show us what you tried. You know, let $U=\bigcup U_i$ and $s_i:U_i\to\overline{\mathcal{F}}$ a family of sections which agree on the overlaps, can you define a unique section $s:U\to\overline{\mathcal{F}}$ extending all the others?

thats true sir , but the word discontinuous  is bugging me

The idea is that the sections might be, or might not be, continuous. It's only there because usually one thinks only about continuous sections; so you can ignore the word and just think about functions in general which are right inverses to $\pi$
